# Vlookup with Exact match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, exact-match

I am trying to do Exact match using Vlookup but it is not working with this formula.

```
IF(EXACT(A4,VLOOKUP(A4,'names'B:B,1,FALSE))=TRUE,VLOOKUP(A4,'names'B:B,2,FALSE),"False")
```

I have a tab which looks like this:

[image]

I have one more tab with in same spread sheet called names and looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to find the exact match of name  from tab 1 with names and display True/False values in column D of the tab 1

The result that I am expecting is this:

[image]

Could any one please help me?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` has an option for exact match

Comment: @urdearboy I do not believe the exact `vlookup` option is actually case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

`=IFERROR(EXACT(INDEX($A$6:$A$8,MATCH(A3,$A$6:$A$8,0)),A3),FALSE)`

[image]

Comment: Splitting hairs here.  While the above example does work, I thought the OP ask for help using VLOOKUP?

Comment: @ForwardEd - VLOOKUP is evil and I refuse to use it even with a gun pointed at my head.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you beat me to it, but i thought would be nice if you can exctend the list by dragging it downards.

```
=IFERROR(EXACT(INDEX(Names!A$1:A20;MATCH(Sheet1!A18;Names!A$1:A20;0));A18);"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following formulas in at the top of your True/False column and copy down:

```
=ISNUMBER(AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(A1,Names!$B$3:$B$5),1))
```

Adjust your ranges to suit your data.  Note the use of the Sheet name before the ! to indicate that a range of cells is on a different sheet.  Other formulas will work as well as noted with other answer to your question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The above formulas are not working. I have Two sheets. I wanted to compare the names present in both the columns. 
For example: Sheet 1 Column A is names 
Sheet 2 : column B is names
I want to check if a Column A names is present in Column B names list with exact match and if it is present then the formula should display True

Comment: As said in the answer, you need to adjust your ranges (cell references) to suit your data.  I have changed the photo and updated the formulas to match the new photos.

Comment: It works:):) Thank you so much!!!! Is there a way to default the rule check column to blank instead of Falses until we have a name in column B of sheet 1

Comment: Put the whole thing in an IF statement.  `IF(condition, what to do if true, what to do if false)`  so what to do if false is "",  What to do if TRUE can be TRUE or "MATCH".  Condition is anything that returns TRUE or FALSE.  Technically a math operation too with the understanding that 0 is FALSE and anything else is TRUE.

Comment: The formula is failing in the below instance:
sheet 1
REEMA TRUE
arjun TRUE
reema FALSE
Test  FALSE
Names:
REEMA
arjun
reema
ARJUN

Comment: It is failing when both the upper and lower case names are present in both the tabs

Comment: Updated it with an alternate formula.  Because vlookup is not a case sensitive search, It was finding the first occurrence of the name and not skipping over it once found.  In this approach, FIND is case sensitive.  Aggregate with formula 14/15 performs array like operations without being an array.

Comment: The above formula is giving the same error again. Lets say I have Arjun and ARJUN in sheet 1 and in Names sheet, I have ARJUN and Arjun.

the formula gives false for Arjun and True for ARJUN