# Exact match in Columns

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

How would i find an exact match from one range on another range if they don't align.

So if Column 1 has '5' but doesn't show in column 2 to give me false.

[image]

Expecting True or False result

Comment: `=ISNUMERIC(MATCH(B2,A:A,0))`

Comment: Try `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,A$2:A$6,0))`.

Comment: Have a look (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493515/vlookup-with-exact-match?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C63.3658)

Comment: Another option: `=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B46,C2),"yes","no")`